# order by a parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-order-by

Hi i have a store procedure, where i do a select query.
I want order this by an external parameter.

I post an minimal example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_missioni_get_data]
@order VarChar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT  * from missioni ORDER BY ...
END
```

What can i write in order by for do that?

thanks

Comment: How about returning an unsorted dataset and sort the results in code?

Comment: The external parameter you pass in will be static, so how can you order by it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have 2 options, either use a CASE statement, or use dynamic sql

This would be an example of the CASE statement

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Col1 VARCHAR(10),
        Col2 VARCHAR(10)
)

DECLARE @OrderBy VARCHAR(100)

SET @OrderBy = 'Col1'

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table
ORDER BY 
        CASE
            WHEN @OrderBy = 'Col1' THEN Col1
            WHEN @OrderBy = 'Col2' THEN Col2
            ELSE Col1
        END
```

And this would be and example of dynamic sql

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (
        Col1 VARCHAR(10),
        Col2 VARCHAR(10)
)

DECLARE @OrderBy VARCHAR(100)

SET @OrderBy = 'Col1'

DECLARE @SqlString NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SqlString = 'SELECT * FROM #Table ORDER BY ' + @OrderBy

EXEC(@Sqlstring)

DROP TABLE #Table
```

Comment: If you use the Case/When method, it's VERY important that each column has the same data type.  SQL evaluates the resulting data type of a Case/When expression at compile time and uses data type precedence to determine the output data type.  Try mixing an integer column with a DateTime column and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use an expression for the column that you want to sort by.

```
DECLARE @OrderBy INT

SET @OrderBy = 4

SELECT     *
FROM         MySourceTable
ORDER BY COL_NAME(OBJECT_ID('MySourceTable'), @OrderBy )
```

It is usually better to avoid dynamic sql if you can.

Answer (score -1):

You are going to have use string concatenation and [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).