# Force Parameterization of Entity Framework Order By

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using something similar to DynamicLinq to allow Entity Framework results to be ordered by a string that corresponds to a property name. However, it seems that whenever the sort property is changed, the cached SQL is not used an instead a new statement is generated. What I am looking for is a way to get Entity Framework to use a SQL parameter for the ORDER BY clause in the SQL statements it generates.

I was able to overcome a similar issue with the .Skip() and .Take() methods. So the corresponding SELECT TOP N and WHERE ROW_NUMBER > M are correctly parameterized in the SQL output.

Is there any way to get the SQL output to use an ORDER BY clause that is something like:

```
ORDER BY [Foo].[@p__linq__24]
```

From a SQL standpoint, this should be possible.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but, as you've stated it, using a parameter there isn't allowed.

Comment: related, but not quite a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378728/order-by-a-parameter

Comment: How were you able to do it with `Skip` and `Take`?

Comment: @BenAaronson look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201403/force-entity-framework-to-use-sql-parameterization-for-better-sql-proc-cache-reu

Comment: @hometoast it SHOULD be possible do to it in SQL with sp_executesql and a dynamic SQL statement, which is exactly how Entity Framework works.

Comment: thanks @user653649, I hadn't considered `sp_executesql`

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't accept parameters for `ORDER BY`.

But, apart from this detail, and more important is this: when a query is going to be executed, SQL server creates the optimal query execution plan. When doing this, it decides which indices to use, how rows are filtered, how tables are combined and so on. And changing the order of the result is not so trivial as to expect that the previous execution plan is still valid (for example it can decide to use a different index).

In other words, an execution plan is re-used only if the changes in the query are trivial (like changing the value of a filter). And even so, depending on the statistics and selectivity of the filtering value, it could decide to do it in a different way. For example imagine a bit colum which has 999 rows with value 0, and 1 column with value 1. If the statistics are correctly updated, SQL server knows that filtering by the value 1 is optimal in this index (extremely selective), and filtering by 0 is pointless (nearly non selective).

Unless you're facing extreme cases where you really need to optimize, don't worry about this.

You can make your own tests checking the "Show query execution plan" in SSMS and looking at the execution plan (the real one, not the stimated... I don't know the exact wording in English, I've got localized SSMS).

Comment: I'm not trying to optimize the SQL plan, but rather force Entity Framework to use the same SQL statement for a query regardless of the order by property. Entity Framework uses parameterized dynamic SQL statements to execute it's queries. Meaning that the items in the where clauses are parameters passed into a sql statement. These statements are cached. This way it doesn't have to compile the whole expression tree into sql every time. For complex queries, this is a huge performance booster. I'm looking for a way to parameterize the order by clause, in the same fashion as the where clause.

Comment: EVen if what you want to do is on the EF side, order by cannot beparameterized. Have you measured the "performance boost" or are you just imagining it? You should not worry about performance, unless it's clear that there is a serious performance problem. You can be interested in reading this extensive article on EF optimizations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/hh949853, specially 3.2.2